# Can not debug Outlook add-in with VS

Tags: c#, debugging, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I installed windows completely new and installed VS 2019 and Outlook Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019.

I created a new Outlook VSTO add-in project with C# and .NET 4.7.2

I pressed F5 and got the following error:

Customized functionality in this application will not work because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for

How can I solve this problem? I have the same problem on my Laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new certificate in the project options. Or trust the old certificate from your other machine.

Comment: I created the project on my PC and I'm debugging it on my PC. Why can it not work out of the box? The last times I have developed add-ins it just worked. Creating a new Test certificate did not work, i still get the error

Comment: Can you reproduce the error? Just create a new outlook project and start it

Comment: Yes, the self-created certificate used to sign your addin is only trusted on the machine where it was created. Create a new certificate on the second machine or use a certificate that both machines trust.

Comment: As i said i create the project on my desktop computer and start it there too. The laptop is not involved. I just said that i have done the same thing on my laptop too and it did not work there too

Comment: Did you create a brand new addin on the laptop (or wherever the error is shown)?

Comment: What do you see on the Signing tab of your project properties in VS?

Comment: Yes, just installed vs and created the project and started it

Comment: Fixed it, please look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Granting Trust to Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772086.aspx) article which states the following:

If you sign the solution with a known and trusted certificate, the solution will automatically be installed without prompting the end user to make a trust decision. **After a certificate is obtained, the certificate must be explicitly trusted by adding it to the Trusted Publishers list.**

For more information, see [How to: Add a Trusted Publisher to a Client Computer for ClickOnce Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172241.aspx).

You may find the [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx#Trust) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, for me the problem was that I used a key management server for licensing outlook. Something was wrong with it, so I purchased a new office key and installed it again but this time the retail edition. Now it works like expected